# Xamarin Portable OnAppearing() XAML page loading

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

i am using the Xamarin Forms Portable project and i am using the MVVM method. Right now I am stuck. I want to build a LOADING page. So when the (Custom) Page starts it must load a XAML page loading and when the Loading (call to a webservice) is done the XAML page loading must be set to visible = false.

I have the next code that wont work:

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {

        base.OnAppearing();

        var page = Navigation.PushAsync(new ActivityIndicatorPage());

        await Task.Delay(1000);

        BindingContext = new ProductViewModel(_ProductId);

    }
```

So how do i Call the 'ActivityIndicatorPage' Page and then set it to invisible after the 'BindingContext = new ProductViewModel(_ProductId);' call is done.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You need an [AcitvityIndicator](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/)
Just include this code in your xaml page where you want to show the loading
and bind `IsVisible` property of `StackLayout` or whatever you choose as a container.

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}">
    <ActivityIndicator Color="Red" IsRunning="true" />
</StackLayout>
```

then you can set its bindable property(or name of `StackLayout` whatever in your case) to true or false based on your background task completion
for example: in your code behind or in `viewModel` you can do something like this

```
public async Task<bool> MyBackgroundTask(){
    IsLoading=true
    //your background task
    if(successful){
        IsLoading = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Aftering triggering my Model (ProductViewModel) I have the 'LoadData' class. // public async Task LoadData() { IsLoading = true; Task<Product> _product = GetProductOnlineWebservice(_productId); var _Prod = await _product; NotifyAllPropertiesChanged(); IsLoading = false;} not working :(

Comment: First make sure `ActivityIndicator` view is properly placed and visible in the page by setting the `<StackLayout IsVisible="true"/>` or remove that `StackLayout` initially. after that you can assign a name to the `StackLayout` and change its `IsVisible property` in the code behind. after this behaviour is working you can bind it with your `ViewModel` property.

Comment: HI @Fahadsk, thanx for your help but i am a Xamarin Rooki. Do you have a example please?

Comment: It just does not work. Going crazy :( ... 

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{

    base.OnAppearing();

    var page = Navigation.PushAsync(new ActivityIndicatorPage());

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    BindingContext = new ProductViewModel(_ProductId);

}`code` 

The ProductViewModel is the model that gets the Webservice data. But the AcitivityIndicator will just not trigger.

Comment: private List<ProductSearchResults> _productSearchList;

        public ProductSearchViewModel(string _Name) : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
        {

            _SearchName = _Name;
            ThumbnailHeight = 100;

            Windows_On_Load();

        }

        async void Windows_On_Load()
        {

            IsLoading = true;

            await Task.Delay(1000); //Simulates 1 second wait

            LoadData();

            IsLoading = false;

        }

It only works with the Task.Delay.

Is there a another way?

Comment: @Ekrem kindly update this in your question so that it can be easily understood and u can get better answers for this.